# Power Bi Removing filters

Tags: powerbi

I am new to power bi and I am working on visualisations but I am having some trouble how do I get distinct values in a slicer.

I am wondering how does one remove duplicates from a slicer filter using dax or is their a simpler way.

I am using excel as my data source.

I am using a column called Period which has data like the following.

12
13
14
15
15

But there are duplicates in the source data which I dont no how to filter only on the slicer.

Comment: Slicers generally do this automatically. Can you show us what you're seeing and what you want instead?

Comment: @AlexisOlson shown about just a simple numeric field but it has duplicates in source data.

Comment: Like I said, slicers should automatically not show duplicates. If you are seeing duplicates, please post a screenshot as that is not expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The slicer will only display DISTINCT values BUT if you have duplicate values in your source data you'll need to account for it. You can do this by creating a simple measure on whatever field you are slicing using some logic or built in functions like DISTINCTCOUNT, DISTINCT, VALUES etc..